# Locale setting in windows

Tags: windows, encoding, locale

Is it possible to set the en_US locale in Windows OS especially Windows 2008 with
character set as ISO-8859-1? and verify it?

In linux I am able to differentiate between two locales
en_US and en_US.UTF-8 by setting it in /etc/sysconfig/i18n. verified it using "locale -a -v"

```
locale: en_US           archive: /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive

    title | English locale for the USA
   source | Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  address | ....
    email | ....
 language | English
territory | USA
 revision | 1.0
     date | 2000-06-24
  codeset | ISO-8859-1
```

locale: en_US.utf8      archive: /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
    title | English locale for the USA
   source | Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  address | 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA
    email | bug-glibc-locales@gnu.org
 language | English
territory | USA
 revision | 1.0
     date | 2000-06-24
  codeset | UTF-8